# Cocos2d-x V3 How to override ::create() properly?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have Player class defined like this:

"Player.h"

```
#ifndef PLAYER_h
#define PLAYER_h

#include "cocos2d.h"

USING_NS_CC;

class Player: public Sprite {
public:
     Player();
     ~Player();


private:
    Sprite *playerSprite;

    __String name;

    int maxHP;
    int currHP;

    int maxMP;
    int currMP;

    int maxEXP;
    int currEXP;
 };

#endif
```

and "Player.cpp":

```
#include "Player.h"
```

I want to initialize int maxHP, int maxMP .. etc upon

```
Player* myPlayer = Player::create();
```

What would be the proper way to override ::create() function with parameters such that

```
// create(int maxHP, int currHP, int maxMP, int currMP, int maxEXP, int currEXP)
Player* myPlayer = Player::create(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100);
```

can be used?

Comment: Why create players in a `create` static function if you can do it in the constructor? You should do away with the pointers and utilize RAII.

Comment: Also, why does your player both inherit `sprite` and contain it?

Comment: @Ivan Rubinson How can i assign a sprite to this class? I'm not quite getting this sprite inheritance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `Player* player = new Sprite();`? That's not right. Think of inheritance as "IS-A", and composition as "HAS-A". Is a player a sprite? Or does it have a sprite?

Comment: @IvanRubinson I was looking at this link for now:
http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/creating-a-sprite-from-a-subclass-of-ccsprite/3351

maybe this is the solution to my secondary question on the sprite?

What i was trying to do was create "Player" class that is actually a Sprite with some private variables(HP, MP, EXP, etc).

Comment: My eyes are bleeding. This is not right. That is not how to use C++.

Comment: @IvanRubinson My brain is bleeding. Can you teach me briefly on how I can accomplish this? I want to "this->addChild(player);", where "player" is an image(=Sprite) that has "int HP", "int MP", etc. So when HP is decreased, I want to make this "player" Sprite blink or whatever.

Comment: Don't inherit from Sprite. But thats a code review discussion. Ask it on the [code review stack exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overload `create` (have multiple functions with the same name but different signature).

```
class Player : public Sprite {
public:
    static Player* create(int maxHP, int currHP, int maxMP, int currMP, int maxEXP, int currEXP) {
        Player* p = Player::create();
        p->maxHP = maxHP;
        // etc ...
        return p;
    }
}
```